# Lost all hdd partitions. Formatting fails

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I lost all partition hard drive (1 TB). It's completely formatted. Now it's in ext4 file system. I cannot make partition from that 1 TB. I used terminal window and tried to make it as a Linux logical volume manager, but failed.

Image showing my disks in Gparted:

[image]

Terminal window making Linux logical volume manager failed while writing:

[image]

please help me to fix this....

Comment: fix what? the formatting? or just forget about it and getting a new OS on it?

Comment: Do you need to get your data back?

Comment: i need to partition my disk and need to install windows along with linux

Answer (score 1):

The message about the kernel using the old table, appears because you are trying to modify partitions on a disk that's in use by the system.  Either boot from a LiveCD and make the changes you want on your disk or, as Rinzwind said, do a clean install.

If this disk is not your system disk, you can also unmount it before you start making this kind of changes.

If it is, reboot as instructed by `fdisk` for the changes to be used.